# Predicate Logic proof: $\forall x\in S\exists y\in S p(x,y)\to \exists y\in Sp(y,y)$

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

For any non-empty set $S$ and predicate $p$ defined on $S^2$ prove or disprove
$\forall x\in S\exists y\in S p(x,y)\to \exists y\in Sp(y,y)$

I'm trying to prove the above.
First of all i need to know whether the statement is true or false..
Here how to change $p(x,y)$ to $p(y,y)$??
pretty confused..

Comment: Please check that I didn't change the meaning of your question by rewriting it in $\LaTeX$.

Comment: yeah its ok do you have any idea of whether its true or false ?

Comment: Check my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Let $S:=\Bbb Z$ and for all $(x,y)\in S^2$ and let $p(x,y)$ mean $x>y$.

Comment: Ooops sorry but the sum is given for non-empty set S

Comment: @emil Edit that into the question.

Comment: Sorry I've just started logic one month ago. So i don't have much knowledge on that. Can you please explain it to me?

Comment: @emil Sure, but help me help you. Do you know what a [conditional statement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional) is?

Comment: guess so.. if one side is true does it imply the other side ?

Comment: So here we're assuming that for every x there's a y that satisfies "p" predicate e.g.x+y=1,,, and then what?? what does p(y,y) mean?

Comment: @emil A conditional statement is a statement that 'looks like' $A\to B$. They can either be true or false. What you said above is a property of all **true** conditional statements, namely that if $A$ is true, then so is $B$. Do you know what do you have to do prove that a conditional statement is false?

Comment: is it finding one example to disprove the statement?

Comment: @emil That's true for all statements. How do you disprove a conditional statement?

Comment: Assume something true and come up with a contradiction.

Comment: @emil To disprove a conditional statement $A\to B$. You need to find an instance in which $A$ is true and $B$ is false. Having this mind and looking at my answer, can you manage to understand the problem?

Comment: But first of all i need to know what the predicate p(y,y) mean? can u give me a simple example to that?
like p(x,y) means something like x+y=1

Comment: @emil $p(x,y)$ can mean anything. If you want to prove that the statement is false, you can give it a meaning as you wish to make the statement false. If you want to prove the statement is true, you need to prove that it is true regardless of what $p(x,y)$ means. In my answer I gave you a possible meaning for $p(x,y)$ to make the statement false.

Comment: I am really sorry i have to go now, I really appreciate you tried to help me. I need to understand this subject a lot more.

Comment: @emil No problem. Come back later with questions if you need. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement would be true in some cases, e.g. if $S$ is a singleton.

Your statement would be false, however, if $S=\{ x,y\}$ where $x\neq y$, and

$\forall a,b\in S(P(a,b)\leftrightarrow a\neq b)$.

This doesn't formally *disprove* your statement, but it does suggest that it is not true in general. Maybe that will suffice for your purposes, but I don't think it is possible to formally prove or disprove your statement  as it stands, using ordinary logic and set theory.